# Why does Ubuntu create the file /var/log/boot?

Tags: log

Why does Ubuntu 10.04.4 and 11.10 create the file /var/log/boot and does not fill it except with the text: "(Nothing has been logged yet.)"?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive and convincing answer.

Comment: If an answer solves your question, [please mark it as accepted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1137/6969).

Answer (score 4):

The reason it is empty is that bootlogd is disabled by default.

If you wish to see boot messages in the log you need to enable it.

Do Alt+F2 to open Run Dialogue

[image]

Then Change

BOOTLOGD_ENABLE=No

to

BOOTLOGD_ENABLE=Yes

Save and exit gedit.

This is what it looks like here - decide if the information is important to you and enable if you wish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable boot logging by opening a terminal and typing the following:

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/default/bootlogd
```

The text editor will open, and the following will be show:

```
BOOTLOGD_ENABLE=No
```

Change BOOTLOGD_ENABLE to yes

Now, everytime you restart, /var/log/boot will be created, and it will contain a log of all your boot messages. You need to be root to open it, so you can easily open it up again with sudo.

source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=49925

Comment: Could you expand your answer to include some of the tips found in that forum post?  That would make this answer more useful.

Answer (score -3):

If it's not installed by default:

```
apt-get install bootlogd
```

Then make sure /etc/default/bootlogd has BOOTLOGD_ENABLE=Yes.

Comment: Please do not kick old unsupported releases with an answer that is already provided. Besides that: is IS installed by default, it is not enabled by default.

Comment: It was not installed by default on Ubuntu server 15.04 on 14.10 desktop. That's the reason I kicked this conversation.
I meant to say "if it's not installed by default" - just saw my typo and edited my answer.

Comment: This is about 10.04.4 and 11.10. Back then things where different.

Comment: @Rinzwind Not inistalled by default in 15.04.

Comment: This is a question specific to an old release of Ubuntu, so please [edit] your answer and improve it, and leave me a note @Fabby so I'll come and remove the negative reputation points you've now accrued.  Alternatively, [delete] the answer entirely and the negative points will reverse as well.  (I do the same with answers that give me negative rep.)

Comment: So it's more important to have correct procedures over helping each other.? You are seriously spending time on putting negative points for an answer that tries to help out folks who search for the exact same problem? I'm perplexed and feel sad about what AskUbuntu has become.  Time to switch.

Comment: No, no, please! Helping each other is more important! But in this case, the **question is specific to an old version**...  If you want to have such an answer for newer versions, [create a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask), ask a question on Precise, Trusty and/or Utopic  and then answer your own question!  Feel free to drop by in the [general UA chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) to discuss further...